# How to get real link from "Save link as" icon

Tags: imacros

I'm new to coding in iMacros. Maybe someone could help me.

I want to download several files from a website, but to download each file manually I need to do "rigth click" over an icon then "Save link as" and select a folder and click "Ok"

I tried recording my steps but the "save link as", folder selection and click "ok" weren't recorded.

I saved the HTML code of the website and I see that the visible links that request me to "Save link as" are like this:

```
    http://website.com/ab/cd/kpppwo/file_xyz.mp3
```

When I go manually in browser to `http://website.com/ab/cd/kpppwo/file_xyz.mp3` it opens a new tab with a very long URL. If I put this long URL in browser the file can be downloaded.

So, having the short links (from HTML code of website), how can I get the long URL for each short URL and save the long URLs in a csv file. Or how to download directly with a iMacro code from website automating the save as process?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess you should simply use the [SAVETARGETAS](https://wiki.imacros.net/SAVETARGETAS) event. For more details, take a look at the [demo](https://wiki.imacros.net/Demo-SaveTargetAs). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I see your example. I tested with simpler script but has many links and I see that I need a loop but free version doesn't allow more than 3 and use JavaScript or Vbs code to make a loop and connect with a imm macro doesn't work either with newer version of Firefox I used only in paid version :(

Comment: FYI. In such cases I prefer using [iMacros for Firefox v. **8.9.7**](https://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox_Legacy) (the best free legacy version) along with Firefox Portable up to v. **55**.